# Convert Datetime to Date

Tags: magento-1.9, php, date

I am having trouble pulling the date out of a datetime in magento.

Currently the date gets called using:

```
$_formatDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(
                Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM
            );
$create_time = Mage::app()->getLocale()
                ->date($_order->getData('created_at'), Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT)->toString($_formatDate);
```

I need the date in the format d-m-Y but I can't seem to work it out. I need something like:

```
$create_date = $create_time->toString('d-m-Y')
```

Comment: have you tried $create_date = date_format($create_time, 'd-m-Y'); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$create_time = Mage::app()->getLocale()
        ->date($_order->getData('created_at'), Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT)->getTimestamp();
```

This will give you the timestamp and to transform it in the format you like use this:

```
$created_time = date('d-m-Y', $create_time);
```

I tested it and it works!